# Record not inserted into database without any error

Tags: php

I have android app to upload image to server and save some records to database, the uploaded image is saved in folder as expected but the php statement to save record in database not work and save nothing without any error show.

my php script

```
$hostname = "localhost";

$username = "username";

$password = "password";

 $dbname = "dbname";

 $con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);
 if(isset($_POST['image'])){
$image = $_POST['image'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$type= $_POST['type'];
$desc= $_POST['desc'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$token= $_POST['token'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
upload($_POST['image']);
exit;
}
else{
echo "image_not_in";
exit;
 }
function upload($image){
//create unique image file name based on micro time and date
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
$id = $now->format('YmdHisu');

$upload_folder = "Uploads"; //DO NOT put url (http://example.com/upload)
$path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";

//Cannot use "== true"
if(file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image)) != false){


   $sql= "INSERT INTO donor(name, donor_phone, donor_type, donor_desc, address, donor_img, token) values('$name', '$type', '$phone', '$desc', '$address', '$path', '$token')";



        $response["success"]=1;
        echo json_encode($response);

  }
 else{

        $response["error"]=2;
        echo json_encode($response);

 }

}
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: I see an SQL query but you're doing anything with it

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually executing the query after building it. What you need is to add, right after defining $sql, something like this:

```
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql) === TRUE) {
   $response["success"]=1;
   echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
   $response["error"]=2;
   echo json_encode($response);
}
```

You should check the php manual for [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).